# python argparse default value for optional argument

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

```
usage:  [-h] [--foo FOO] bar
```

1. How do I make sure that default value of FOO is `abc` if I execute my script like below

`./myscript.py --foo bar` --> `bar` is positional argument here. but `args.foo` is considering `bar` as argument of `'--foo'`. I want `args.foo` to be `abc` and `bar` to be the positional argument

Answer (score 3):

You can't, not without reworking your arguments.

You should use *two* switches here; one to switch on the behaviour, and one to override the default value picked. You can make the second switch imply the first:

```
usage: [-h] [--foo] [--foo-setting FOO] bar
```

where `--foo` is a boolean switch that toggles the behaviour, and `--foo-setting` lets you set the configuration for the switch:

```
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--foo-setting', help='Set the value for foo, implies --foo is given')

# ...
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.foo_setting is not None:
    # default was overridden, explicitly enable the foo feature
    args.foo = True

if args.foo:
    foo_feature_setting = args.foo_setting or 'default value'
```

Comment: The problem is, I want to add to mutual exclusive group. Is it possible to have multiple option in one set of the group?

Comment: @tez: no; but you are free to add additional tests after parsing. If `foo_setting` was set but another mutually exclusive group option was picked, then that's an error you need to manually detect.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `--` to separate the `--foo` argument(s) from the `bar`?

---

With this basic setup:

```
p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--foo',nargs='?',const='abc', default='other')
p.add_argument('bar')

In [633]: p.parse_args(['bar'])
Out[633]: Namespace(bar='bar', foo='other')

In [634]: p.parse_args(['bar','--foo'])
Out[634]: Namespace(bar='bar', foo='abc')

In [635]: p.parse_args(['bar','--foo','test'])
Out[635]: Namespace(bar='bar', foo='test')

In [636]: p.parse_args(['--foo','bar'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--foo [FOO]] bar
'error message'
```

The plain `--foo` can occur AFTER `bar`.  'other' ('default`) is the value it gets if absent, 'abc' (the`const`) the value it gets if present but 'empty'.

But as you found out, when `--foo` is first it consumes the following string, leaving nothing for the `positional` argument.  In other words, when handling `--foo`, it does not take into account the future needs of `bar`.

If I add another argument

```
p.add_argument('--baz',action='store_true')
p.parse_args(['--foo','--baz','bar'])
# Namespace(bar='bar', baz=True, foo='abc')
```

This works because `--baz` marks the end of `--foo` arguments.

You can also use `--` to mark the end of `optionals` and the start of `postionals`:

```
p.parse_args(['--foo','--','bar'])
```

There is a `bug issue` that tries to rectify this by reserving strings for trailing `positionals` 
http://bugs.python.org/issue9338 `argparse optionals with nargs='?', '*' or '+' can't be followed by positionals`

But the patch is not trivial.  `--` is your best tool at this time.

I don't follow your comment to Martijn about mutually exclusive group(s).